# normal vectors in spaces where $n > 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors

I am reading Lovelock and Rund's book on Tensors and they make a statement that I wanted to validate about normal vectors in high-dimensional spaces.

> It should be remarked that the above geometrical definition of $A \times B$ is meaningful solely for the case of a three-dimensional space, because in a higher-dimensional space the plane $C$ does not possess a unique normal.

I was just wondering why planes in high dimensional spaces do not possess unique normals?

Comment: given $n-1$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n,$ there is a one-dimensional orthogonal space; the generalized cross product is given by putting the $n-1$ vactors as rows in a square matrix, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra

Comment: Oh, note that the matrix displayed in the Wikipedia description is using both subscripts and superscripts to denote location in the matrix. This is usual practice with many types of tensors, but may be confusing in a matrix, as the superscripts could  be confused with exponents.

Answer (score 0):

The (simple) bivector describing a plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ belongs to a $n(n-1)/2$ dimensional space, which number equals 3 for n=3. In higher dimensions we cannot associate it with a unique n-dimensional normal vector.